# Update using Common Table Expression

Tags: postgresql, sql-update, relationship, common-table-expression

I have a pair of tables in a one to many relationship. I want to insert rows in the One table, rows in the Many table, and then update the new row in the One table.

A simplified structure is as below. There is a fiddle at https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=8555fb74372b91c8854f7a18e78110c0

Everything works except for the last step, where the new rows is supposed to be updated. I get a `NULL` for the updated value.

I can’t see what is missing to get this to work. I suspect it has something to do with the correct syntax to update using the `FROM` clause. According to the documentation, that’s how you can supply additional data to the `UPDATE` statement. On the other hand, there may be something more fundamental.

I know that I can write a function to do this, and I have already done that. Here I want to get a better understanding of the SQL involved.

```sql
CREATE TABLE testsales(
    id int GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    customerid int,
    total decimal(6,2)
);
CREATE TABLE testitems(
    id int GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    saleid int REFERENCES testsales(id),
    productid int,
    quantity int,
    price decimal(5,2)
);

with
    customer(id) as (select 562),
    items(productid,quantity) as (values(1489,2),(746,1),(1093,3)),
    newsale as (
        insert into testsales(customerid)
        select id FROM customer
        returning id
    ),
    addsaleitems as(
        insert into testitems(saleid,productid,quantity,price)
        select
            newsale.id, items.productid, items.quantity,100
        from newsale, items
        returning *
    )
update testsales
set total=(select sum(price*quantity) from addsaleitems)
from addsaleitems,newsale
where testsales.id=newsale.id;
```

In the above sample, the first two CTEs, `customer` and `items` are simply there to provide values for what follows. The `newsale` CTE creates the new row in the One table, `addsaleitems` adds rows to the `Many` table, and the rest of it is supposed to update the One table.

Comment: This is [documented behaviour](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING): "*All the statements are executed with the same snapshot (see Chapter 13), so they cannot “see” one another's effects on the target tables*" - so the final UPDATE doesn't see the rows inserted earlier.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks for the link. Is there any way of doing this? I’m having no success with `UPDATE newsale`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As documented](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING), the `UPDATE` cannot yet see the rows inserted in the same statement.

The trick is to calculate the sum first, right when you insert the row into `testsales`.

Comment: OK, I can see the problem. It’s not hard to fix, so I’ve updated my fiddle to show this. I was trying to find a way to take advantage of the `RETURNING` clause, but I didn’t know about this behaviour. Thanks.